# How to run keychain from gdm ?

Tags: ssh, gpg-agent, gdm3, gnupg

I have keychain manage both ssh-agent and gpg-agent. It's working from a shell, with a line like:

`` eval `keychain --eval --agents ssh,gpg id_rsa my_gpg_key` ``

in ~/.bash_profile.

I'd like to have keychain run from the gdm login. Both ssh-agent and gpg-agent allow for a graphical prompt for the passphrase: `export SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass` for ssh-agent and `pinentry program=/usr/bin/pinentry-gnome3` for gpg-agent.

keychain uses the gnome-ssh-askpass dialog but somehow reverts to a ncurses dialog for gpg-agent.

Can keychain be made to ask for both gpg and ssh passphrases in a dialog box so that one can invoke if from the gdm session scripts ?